# DataContext is not initializing when I declare on design time in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datacontext

I am DataContext at design time, but it is not initializing at run time. It is null at runtime. Here is my xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="HRBMS.Desktop.Views.User.ucUser"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HRBMS.Desktop.Views.User"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 

             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:HRBMS.Desktop.ViewModels.User"
             DataContextChanged="UserControl_DataContextChanged"

             xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:HRBMS.Desktop.Views"

             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:UserViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
             >
```

I am new to wpf, can anyone draw my attention where I am making mistake ?

Answer (score 2):

d:DataContext is only design-time. if you want to have that datacontext during runtime, you can create it like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:UserViewModel />
</UserControl.DateContext>
```

or you can define it in the code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.DataContext = new UserViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Okay I got it. So I have to add the following in xaml to initialize datacontext at runtime.
    <UserControl.DataContext>
            <viewModels:UserViewModel/>
        </UserControl.DataContext>